# Should I remove asterisk from CSS if site doesn't work in <IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I had someone else help me make my site responsive, the site doesn't work below IE8 since it is using some HTML5 and CSS3 features that aren't supported. So with that said I have a CSS class that is only an asterisk. Which I thought was a hack for IE7. Now the thing is is that this is in a media query for media-print. Does this have a different meaning when it is for print media? Would it be okay for me to remove the asterisk and just add the classes names that need to be changed instead? Here is how it looks:

```
@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: black !important;
        box-shadow:none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
        filter:none !important;
        -ms-filter: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: The CSS you are showing should not be able to cause any problems in a browser. Also, why do you thing you should remove the asterisk?

Comment: CSS properties under `@media print` section are only used for printing. And those properties seems to be here for this purpose (no shadows, high contrast colors, no background...).  As putvande said, no way it breaks your design, even in IE7.

Comment: In this context, the asterisk is matching all elements. It essentially removes backgrounds and shadows and sets text color to black for every element when printing. The IE hack requires that the asterisk be in front of a property name, like `*background: transparent;`. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Comment: I wan't to remove it because it won't validate. I know it isn't important but themeforest is very strict and I wanted to get rid of as many errors as possible.

Comment: The only line that generates validation error here is `filter:none` (because MS proprietary DirectX filters were not part of any CSS standard, and modern CSS filters are at the early draft stage). The prefixed `-ms-filter` property makes just warning, not error, and the rest of this code is valid CSS3 (shadows) or even CSS1 (everything else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're showing isn't the sole reason why your site doesn't work. That's just a media query - it says "for any print media (`@media print {`), for every element (`*`), use these styles" .But IE8 and lower can't read media queries, so they will ignore any styles inside a media query.

You could replace the `*` with specific selectors for all the elements that you want. But, since IE8- can't read media queries, it won't change how IE8- print your site.

You may want to consider something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or the [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to help older versions of work with newer code. But every site is different.